# Find points along circle

Tags: trigonometry

How can I find the X,Y coordinates for each of the 5 green dots, knowing the **Radius** and **Width** as shown in the image below?

The number of green points along the arc is a variable number, meaning it's not always going to be 5. For this example I chose 5.

The points are always evenly spaced

[image]

Comment: Are the points intended to be evenly spaced along the circumference, i.e., equal angles between them?

Comment: yes they are evenly spaced

Comment: Hint: Use Euler's formula.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the topmost green dot will obviously be the point $(0,20)$. Now on to the next dot. We can draw a right triangle with a hypotenuse connecting the origin to the fifth green dot from the left. Its hypotenuse length will be $20$ and its horizontal leg length will be $4$, so we have that the length of the vertical leg will be $\sqrt{20^2-4^2}=8\sqrt6$. Thus the coordinates of the points farthest from the $y$-axis are $(4,8\sqrt6)$ and $(-4,8\sqrt6)$.

Next, we must do the $2$nd and $4$th points from the left. The angle between the radius to the fourth point and the $y$-axis is half of that between the radius to the fifth point on the $y$-axis, which happens to be $\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)$. Thus the angle between the radius to the fourth point and the $y$-axis is $\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)$. Then the angle between that radius and the $x$-axis is $\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)$, and now since we have and angle and the hypotenuse length of the right triangle to that point, we can find the leg lengths. Let $(a, b)$ and $(-a, b)$ be the coordinates of that point. Then we have
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right)=\frac{a}{20}$$
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right)=\frac{b}{20}$$
meaning that
$$a=20\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right)$$
$$b=20\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right)$$
and so the coordinates of the $2$nd and $4$th points are
$$\left(20\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right), 20\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right)\right)$$
$$\left(-20\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right), 20\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right)\right)$$
respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If there are an odd number of points, then the coordinates of the center one are certainly $(0,20)$.

The coordinates of the outer-most points are $\left(\pm 4,\sqrt{20^2-4^2)}\right)$

The other points are a little trickier. Let $\theta=\sin^{-1}\frac{4}{20}$. If you've got $n$ points, then the angle between adjacent ones is $\phi=\frac{2\theta}{n-1}$. Now, you can find the coordinates of each point: $\left(20\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta+k\phi),20\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta+k\phi),\right)$, for $k=0$ to $n-1$.

Comment: I lifted some of your work to get mine to 'hang together' (not proud).

Answer (score 1):

Let $[a, b]$ be subdivided into $n$ subintervals, as follows

$x_{k+1} = a + k \frac{b-a}{n}\;$ for $0 \le k \le n$

Then, by applying [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), if the length of the interval is $\le \ 2 \pi$ the ordered sequence of points $e^{x_ki}$ are equidistant on the unit circle of complex numbers. The length of the swept out arc is of length $b - a$.

If the midpoint $[a, b]$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, the midpoint of the swept out arc will be at the complex number $i$.

The picture in the question shows that the x-coordinates of the outermost points on the circle are plus/minus $4$. Let $\theta=\sin^{-1}\frac{4}{20}$, so that

$a = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$

and

$b = \frac{\pi}{2} + \theta$

and

$\frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{2\theta}{n}$

Let $\phi=\frac{2\theta}{n}$

Answer:

$\left(20\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta+k\phi),20\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta+k\phi)\right)$ with $0 \le k \le n$

In the initial question of '5 green dots', you would set $n$ to $5-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Convenient to view $x$ axis running vertical. $  R= 20 , w=8 , n= 5 $

$$ \sin \beta = \frac{W}{2R} ,\, $$

$$  x= R  \sin ( \frac{1}{n}\cdot \sin^{-1} \frac{W}{2R}) ,\, y= \sqrt{R^2-x^2}. $$